# SoupStrainer with encoding

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote the line below:

```
[x['href'] for x in BeautifulSoup(data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))]
```

The data is achieved by `urllib.urlopen(XXX).read()` in python2.7.

It works well when the XXX is a page that consists of total English characters, such as http://python.org. But when it goes for a page there is some Chinese characters, it fails. 
There will be a KeyError. And `[x for ...]` returns an empty list.

What's more, if there is no `parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')`, it is OK for both.

Is there some bug of SoupStrainer?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import urllib

data = urllib.urlopen('http://tudou.com').read()
[x['href'] for x in BeautifulSoup(data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))]
```

gives the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    [x['href'] for x in BeautifulSoup(data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))]
  File "F:\ActivePython27\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg\BeautifulSoup‌​.py", line 613, in __getitem__
    return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback of the `KeyError` you see, perhaps with a link to a site that gives you that error.

Comment: The traceback does have nothing special. I have tried [x for x in BeautifulSoup(data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))] and it returns an empty list. So there is a KeyError. The site give me the problem is http://www.tudou.com, larges vedio site in China.

Comment: A traceback is meaningful to *us*. Please include it anyway. An empty list would not trigger a key error.

Comment: OK.<br />from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer<br />
import urllib<br />
data = urllib.urlopen('http://www.tudou.com').read()<br />
[x['href'] for x in BeautifulSoup(data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))]<br />

Traceback (most recent call last):<br />
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module><br />
    [x['href'] for x in BeautifulSoup(data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))]<br />
  File "F:\ActivePython27\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg\BeautifulSoup.py", line 613, in __getitem__
    return self._getAttrMap()[key]<br />
KeyError: 'href'

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `<a>` links on that page that do *not* have a `href` attribute. Use the following instead:

```
[x['href'] for x in BeautifulSoup(data, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')) if x.has_key('href')]
```

For example, it is perfectly normal to declare a link target with `<a name="something" />`; you are selecting those tags too, but they do not have a `href` attribute and your code fails on that.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I know there are tag a with no href. But it seems that I have got something wrong before. But can you tell me that why [x['href'] for x in BeautifulSoup(data).findAll('a')] works with the same page with no KeyError?

Comment: @ZhangXiang: The `findAll()` method only returns 787 results, the `SoupStrainer()` parser returns 1462 results.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I have just found the results differ. Thank you answering my boring question.